# Interpretation of Coefficients using spline ns() in glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, splines

Lets say I run the following code:

```
x <- seq(1, 1000)

set.seed(1)
y <- round(runif(n = 1000))

model <- glm(y ~ ns(x, 3), family = 'binomial')

summary(model)
```

And get the following output:

```
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ ns(x, 3), family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.228  -1.141  -1.043   1.201   1.354  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.0914     0.2208   0.414   0.6789  
ns(x, 3)1     0.4549     0.2676   1.700   0.0892 .
ns(x, 3)2    -0.6945     0.5556  -1.250   0.2113  
ns(x, 3)3    -0.1979     0.2253  -0.878   0.3797  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1384.7  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1380.3  on 996  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1388.3

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

How do I interpret each spline coefficients in the b-spline basis? Since ns(x) gives knots at 334 and 667, does `ns(x, 3)1` correspond to the piece-wise function from 0 to 334, `ns(x, 3)2` correspond to piece-wise function from 334 to 667 and so on? What does each dimension of the basis mean?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is unproductive to attempt interpretation of individual coefficients. It is more direct to create predictions along the range of values for the continuous variables with specific values for the factor(categorical) variables. If you want to look at what the basis functions look like, you can view and plot them for your `x`-values.

```
 splines::ns(1:1000,3)
                    1           2             3
   [1,]  0.0000000000 0.000000000  0.0000000000
   [2,] -0.0007613937 0.002284195 -0.0015227965
   [3,] -0.0015227486 0.004568354 -0.0030455695
   [4,] -0.0022840257 0.006852443 -0.0045682952
   [5,] -0.0030451862 0.009136425 -0.0060909501
   [6,] -0.0038061912 0.011420266 -0.0076135107
   [7,] -0.0045670017 0.013703930 -0.0091359533
   omitted the remaining 993 rows

 attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
33.33333% 66.66667% 
      334       667 
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1]    1 1000
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "ns"     "basis"  "matrix"

png(); matplot( splines::ns(1:1000,3), col=c("red","green","blue") ); dev.off()
```

[image]

So the Intercept might be an estimate of the mean of the y variable if the overall trend were fairly flat as in the case of your example, and then any negative coefficient would imply the the shape of the ns-basis curve was flipped over the range to which it applied. If there were a level shift within a ns-basis range, then the associated coefficient might reflect that fact, although the  Intercept might need to be adjusted one way or the other to "set the starting point":

```
#Compare these three simulations:
y1 <- rnorm(100)
y2 <- y1+100
x  <- 1:100
library(splines)
lm(y1 ~ ns(x,3))
#-------------------------
Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ ns(x, 3))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    ns(x, 3)1    ns(x, 3)2    ns(x, 3)3  
     0.2155      -0.2104      -0.2884       0.2293  
#-----------
lm(y2 ~ ns(x,3))

#--- Intercept picks up the 100 bias in new situation
Call:
lm(formula = Y2 ~ ns(x, 3))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    ns(x, 3)1    ns(x, 3)2    ns(x, 3)3  
   100.2155      -0.2104      -0.2884       0.2293  
#---------------
y1[34:65] <- y1[34:65]+3  # build a level shift in the middle of y1
lm(y1 ~ ns(x,3))


# ----- the Intercept moves "down" to make room for the upshift in the middle
Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ ns(x, 3))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    ns(x, 3)1    ns(x, 3)2    ns(x, 3)3  
    -0.9333       1.8930       4.0145      -1.6712
```

If you're feeling confused then do remember that I told you not to attempt this. An alternate spline basis is the restricted cubic splines (`rcs`-function)  that Frank Harrell advocates and uses to great effect. They lend themselves a bit more to immediate interpretation, but Frank advises not spending much effort at doing so. He does provide a handy `Formula` function for exporting the prediction calculations. If you're in R though, JUST USE `predict`.